# Activate partial visible tab and display complete tab on click of it from the list of horizontal tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently, I'm having a list of tabs visible horizontally. On click of tab it should show me the complete text tab.

Expected Behavior:
When i click on the partly visible tab, it should show me the complete tab by moving left side, same thing should be applicable if I'm doing it from right side(Scroll right if it is first tab).
Text content is dynamic, it can have any number of words. We need to fit it dynamically.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/kzLexmh9/1/

In my current example "HelloWorldFour" is partially displaying. OnClick it should show me the full text by moving the scroll content to left.

HTML:

```
<div class="group" id="frames">
    <div class="item frames-item">HelloWorldOne</div>
    <div class="item frames-item">HelloWorldTwo</div>
    <div class="item frames-item">HelloWorldThree</div>
    <div class="item frames-item">HelloWorldFour</div>
    <div class="item frames-item">HelloWorldFive</div>
    <div class="item frames-item">HelloWorldSix</div>
    <div class="item frames-item">HelloWorldSeven</div>
    <div class="item frames-item">HelloWorldEight</div>
    <div class="item frames-item">HelloWorldNine</div>
    <div class="item frames-item">HelloWorldTen</div>
    <div class="item frames-item">HelloWorldEleven</div>
    <div class="item frames-item">HelloWorldTwelve</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
  $("#frames").on('click', function (e) {
     if (e.target.classList.contains('item')) {
        e.target.parentNode.scrollLeft = e.target.offsetLeft;
     }
  });
```

CSS:

```
   body {
        background: red;
    }
    .group{
        width: 400px;
        display: flex;
        position: relative; /* This is important for the js offsetLeft property */
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }

    .item{
        width: 200px;
        background: #eee;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for? This will work on any of the "HelloWorld" boxes..

***EDIT:***

So I was finally able to get this to work... It is essentially a two part process.. I have added examples to the demo snippet showing how each step works.

*How this works:*

1. Calculate the position to scroll the `div` (that we just clicked) all the way to the left side of the parent container (this was my previous answer)
2. Calculate the 'offset' needed to scroll the `div` (that we just clicked) back to the right
3. Scroll to that position
4. These calculations are determined before any scrolling is performed, so it is a seamless scroll - the calculation is a two part process, but the scrolling is done using the final calculation.

There are 3 demos in this snippet, make sure to scroll down all the way to test them all.

```js
$(".item1").on('click', function(event) {
  finalSolution(this, "#frames1", 400);
});

$(".item2").on('click', function(event) {
  zeroLeftOnly(this, "#frames2", 800);
});

$(".item3").on('click', function(event) {
  animatedSteps(this, "#frames3", 800);
});

function finalSolution(element, container, scrollSpeed) {
  const zeroLeft = $(element).position().left + $(container).scrollLeft();
  const offsetLeft = $(container).width() - $(element).width();
  const scrollTo = zeroLeft - offsetLeft;
  $(container).animate({ scrollLeft: scrollTo }, scrollSpeed);
}

function zeroLeftOnly(element, container, scrollSpeed) {
  const zeroLeft = $(element).position().left + $(container).scrollLeft();
  $(container).animate({ scrollLeft: zeroLeft }, scrollSpeed);
}

function animatedSteps(element, container, scrollSpeed) {
  const zeroLeft = $(element).position().left + $(container).scrollLeft();
  $(container).animate({ scrollLeft: zeroLeft }, scrollSpeed);
  const offsetLeft = $(container).width() - $(element).width();
  const scrollTo = zeroLeft - offsetLeft;
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(container).animate({ scrollLeft: scrollTo }, scrollSpeed);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

h3{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline white;
  margin: 5px;
}

.group {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 38px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  /* This is important for the js offsetLeft property */
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
  width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clickme {
  background: lightblue;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Final Solution</h3>
<p><i><b><small>Click on 'HelloWorldFour' (the light blue block)</small></b></i></p>
<div class="group" id="frames1">
    <div class="item1 frames-item">HelloWorldOne</div>
    <div class="item1 frames-item">HelloWorldTwo</div>
    <div class="item1 frames-item">HelloWorldThree</div>
    <div class="clickme item1 frames-item">HelloWorldFour</div>
    <div class="item1 frames-item">HelloWorldFive</div>
    <div class="item1 frames-item">HelloWorldSix</div>
    <div class="item1 frames-item">HelloWorldSeven</div>
    <div class="item1 frames-item">HelloWorldEight</div>
    <div class="item1 frames-item">HelloWorldNine</div>
    <div class="item1 frames-item">HelloWorldTen</div>
    <div class="item1 frames-item">HelloWorldEleven</div>
    <div class="item1 frames-item">HelloWorldTwelve</div>
</div><br /><hr />
<h3>Each step is animated here - to show how the underlying calculation works.</h3>
<p><i><b><small>Click on 'HelloWorldFour' (the light blue block)</small></b></i></p>
<div class="group" id="frames3">
    <div class="item3 frames-item">HelloWorldOne</div>
    <div class="item3 frames-item">HelloWorldTwo</div>
    <div class="item3 frames-item">HelloWorldThree</div>
    <div class="clickme item3 frames-item">HelloWorldFour</div>
    <div class="item3 frames-item">HelloWorldFive</div>
    <div class="item3 frames-item">HelloWorldSix</div>
    <div class="item3 frames-item">HelloWorldSeven</div>
    <div class="item3 frames-item">HelloWorldEight</div>
    <div class="item3 frames-item">HelloWorldNine</div>
    <div class="item3 frames-item">HelloWorldTen</div>
    <div class="item3 frames-item">HelloWorldEleven</div>
    <div class="item3 frames-item">HelloWorldTwelve</div>
</div><br /><hr />
<h3>Using only 'zeroLeft' - this was my first, older, answer.</h3>
<p><i><b><small>Click on 'HelloWorldFour' (the light blue block)</small></b></i></p>
<div class="group" id="frames2">
    <div class="item2 frames-item">HelloWorldOne</div>
    <div class="item2 frames-item">HelloWorldTwo</div>
    <div class="item2 frames-item">HelloWorldThree</div>
    <div class="clickme item2 frames-item">HelloWorldFour</div>
    <div class="item2 frames-item">HelloWorldFive</div>
    <div class="item2 frames-item">HelloWorldSix</div>
    <div class="item2 frames-item">HelloWorldSeven</div>
    <div class="item2 frames-item">HelloWorldEight</div>
    <div class="item2 frames-item">HelloWorldNine</div>
    <div class="item2 frames-item">HelloWorldTen</div>
    <div class="item2 frames-item">HelloWorldEleven</div>
    <div class="item2 frames-item">HelloWorldTwelve</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it is not working. The click on tab itself is not working.

Comment: Try clicking  partially visible "HelloWorldFour" through your run code snippet it is taking to top of page. Instead it should highlight the complete tab with full label (HelloWorldFour) by moving other tabs left.

Comment: So you're saying you want 'HelloWorldFour' to be all the way left after clicking it?

Comment: HelloWorldFour which is partially visible, should be completely/fully visible on clicking it.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something then because when I click on it, it becomes completely visible. You need to run the Snippet in full screen mode...

Comment: I tried in full screen mode and also added your code in jsfiddle and tested, but no luck.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8i7UICf I am not sure what you're doing wrong...

Comment: Is it possible to share a jsFiddle? You can just fork on top of my fiddle example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204229/discussion-between-harish-ashok-megharaj-and-matt-oestreich).

Comment: Yes, when done in a Fiddle or Snippet here it will scroll your webpage - but if you copy and paste that code into it's own HTML file, that won't happen... I have [made this repo](https://github.com/oze4/scroll-into-view-demo) which you can [view the live website here](https://oze4.github.io/scroll-into-view-demo/) - this shows how you can accomplish it.. I did verify all browsers support `scrollIntoView`.. but it may be a browser issue.. which browser are you using?

Comment: You're right, it is working only in Mozilla browser. If i try the same in chrome and safari it is not working.But i have a scenario were it should support all the browsers.

Comment: But this will move complete set of tabs, I want only one tab to be moved. Same as your imgur example (https://imgur.com/a/8i7UICf)

Comment: @HarishAshokMegharaj I have finally come up with a working solution for this - I updated my answer and the snippet with multiple examples showing how I came to the final solution. Please let me know if this is what you're looking for - I spent a lot of time on this :)

Comment: Excellent, It is perfect solution and you also share all possible scenarios. Thanks a lot for your time, really appreciable

Answer (score 0):

You are just nearby solution. Just try this it to display clicked item at center of group div.

```
e.target.parentNode.scrollLeft = e.target.offsetLeft - e.target.parentNode.offsetWidth/2 ;
```

Comment: As per my example it should just move "HelloWorldFour" and make it fully visible, if i try your code some part of "HelloWorldFive" comes and fit. We are near but not able to come on a full solution.